# music player using java's properties

Tags: java, winamp

I want to do that there will be a music playback program and there will be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use java media framework (jmf)

Comment: I found some links that you are talking about it but the codes dont compile?I dont understand why?  http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html

Comment: u need to install jmf from www.oracle.com . when u will install jmf it class path of jmf.jar will be automatically set.install jmf2.1.1 from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html after that u will be able to compile .

Comment: ok thank you so much Dipen, after installing to my pc anything else to do?

Comment: this installation will add jmf.jar and other jars in your system. so whenever u need import javax.media.*; you need this jar file as library.

Comment: Dipen, I installed  Cross-platform Java for installing. I have JMF-2.1.1e file and some files in it these are, bin, doc and lib. how can i add this lib or how can i do that?

Comment: you need to set class path for that... if u r using windows then when you will install jmf 2.1.1.exe then class path will be automatically set... otherwise u need to set class path manually for other system.

Comment: I think I should install,   Windows Performance Pack for the JMF on the web site, right?

Comment: yes...if u r using windows as platform... and it will also give u GUI to play music also.. or u can manually create code for that too.. for that u need to refer doc of jmf.

Comment: one more question I read on the internet that JMF is not working with  Java SDK 32 bit. is it true?

Comment: it is working properly... bt there may be problem with win 7. i tried on win xp. its working fine on that.

Comment: ups im using win 7 i think i can have a problem with it :s

Comment: there are some security service of win 7 in windows drive(c: drive). bt it is problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use JavaFX, it can play all common media files (native).